# how to use $_POST to relocate few headers in a simpler way?

Tags: php, post, header

Really sorry if I didn't make the title more clear because I am not sure how to express it in just few words.

Here is the thing, I have a dropdown list and let's say the list has the values of

bbyc, dtc, atc, and so on maybe like 10 of them.  And once if I choose the bbyc in the dropdown list then the page will go to bbyc.php

this is what I did.  But I'm wondering if I have 10 of them do I have it do it ten times or there's an easier way?

```
if($_POST["location"] == "bbyc")
{
    header('Location: bbyc.php');
}

if($_POST["location"] == "dtc")
{
    header('Location: dtc.php');
}

if($_POST["location"] == "atc")
{
    header('Location: atc.php');
}
```

P.S. I tried to search something related but I guess I'm not sure how to use an exact word to express what I want so my searches don't work.

Anyways whoever replied thank~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Valid locations.
$options = array(
    'bbyc',
    'dtc',
    'atc',
);

//We have a post
if($_POST) {
    //There is a location set
    if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
        if (in_array($_POST['location'], $options)) {
            //The location is valid, since it's in our options array.
            //Send the user to the location.
            header('Location: ' . $_POST['location'] . '.php');
        } else {
            //We have not found the requested location.
            //Send to error page.
            header('Location: locationNotFound.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was Ninja'd XD.  To add on, it may be a good idea to check `$_POST['location']` against an allowed list.

Comment: Correct, changed it a bit.

Comment: ah thanks...brilliant and if I have more I'll just put it into the array.  BTW if($_POST) is something like if(!(empty($_POST))) right? because I somehow thought if($_POST) only works in frameworks.

Comment: If you have another option, yes, put it in the `array`. the `if()` will work for you as well. No worries there.